# Remove vertical space between several chapters in ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I would like to remove the vertical space between several (but not all) chapters in my ToC (namely, the literature, the list of symbols, and the index). The following code works in the preamble to remove the vertical space between all chapters:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0cm}
```

But this doesn't work for individual chapters. The same question has been asked a lot of times in TeX forums, in particular [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=21946). But I don't know how to use the code there resp. it does not work.

Comment: If the chapter you want to remove the space from are the last ones, add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}}` at the appropriate spot, say before the references.

Comment: Do you use any other sectional packages?

Comment: @egreg Do you want to make that one official?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the parameter `\cftbeforechapskip` at the spot, by adding

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}}
```

in the document, just before the first item where you want this to take effect in the table of contents.

So, if you use `\bibliography{filename}` for the references,

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}}
\bibliography{filename}
```

and similarly if you directly use `\chapter`.

Comment: Nice, another one off the list. Mille grazie.